# SQLcl unable to set spool to file

Tags: oracle, spool, sqlcl

In SQLcl setting spool to file gives error "SP2-0556: Invalid File Name". There are no whitespaces in file name, and the path is correct (folder C:\Temp does exist). Have tried;

```
spool load_data.sql
spool C:\Temp\load_data.sql
spool "C:\Temp\load_data.sql"
```

Using SQLcl 17.2.0 on Win10, OracleXE11.
From sqlplus spool-ing works OK. How can I set SQLcl to spool to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug right now in sqlcl -- seems to be there up through version 17.3
This workaround appears to fix the problem in most o/ses

```
set encoding UTF-8
spool load_data.sql
```

... in windows try this ...

```
set encoding windows-1252
```

Comment: Previous was on unix; here's something I just tried  on my windows 7 and it also works in sqlcl v17.3  :  set encoding windows-1252  Oh yeah, be sure you're running the .bat file

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. I've set encoding to windows-1250 (my Windows locale) and it works.

Comment: When I try this I get SP2-0158: unknown SET option "encoding"   on windows 8 using sqldeveloper

Comment: On Windows 7, defining windows-1252 solve my problem; I voted up :-)